# ODP.Net Managed Driver Ignoring Transaction Rollback

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net-managed

I'm replacing our older unmanaged ODP driver with Oracle's managed driver, and I'm discovering that my transactions are committing even if rolled back explicitly or not committed.

```
var conn = new OracleConnection(...);
conn.Open();
var trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(...);
trans.Rollback();
conn.Close();
```

In this scenario, my insert is committed once the code stops running.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can't replicate; Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0; connection has method CreateCommand, not GetCommand.

Comment: Sorry about that, typed it out on mobile from memory -edited.

Answer (score -2):

Try to specify opened transcation for command after creation -

```
var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.Transaction = trans;        // <----
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this happens implicitly anyways.  Just to be sure, I tried it, but to no effect.